# How UserManager is linked with DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I have the following code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("AssetContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}


public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
              IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
              IOwinContext context)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        return Create(options, dbContext);
    }
    .....
}

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

then I have the controller method:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(UserEditViewModel model)
    {
                var user = mapper.Map<UserEditViewModel, AspNetUser>(model, _db.AspNetUsers.Where(p => p.UserName == model.UserName).FirstOrDefault());

                    user.CompanyId = null;
                    user.LockoutEnabled = false;
                    user.LockoutEndDateUtc = null;


                _db.SaveChanges();

                    var roles = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
                    UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.RoleName);
                    UserManager.RemoveFromRoles(user.Id, roles.ToArray());

                return RedirectToAction("UserList");
    }
```

(please, don't say me about DI, I'm not an owner of code :) )

Problem is that all changes in user :

```
                    user.CompanyId = null;
                    user.LockoutEnabled = false;
                    user.LockoutEndDateUtc = null;
```

is rewritten when I call

```
UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.RoleName);
```

why it happens?

Comment: What do you mean, "is rewritten"? What happens to those values? And what has it to do with your question title "How UserManager is linked with DbContext?
" What excactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

`UserManager` directly depends on `UserStore` and that directly depends on `IdentityDbContext`. Every operation in `UserManager` that involves access to db will be using DbContext. Especially the write operations in `UserManager` will be calling `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`.

If you have the same instance of DbContext used, you will get `SaveChangesAsync()` called on every identity-related write and that will commit all other uncommited changes related to this context.

So what you describe is a consequence of having the same instance of DbContext and calling to save changes (though deep inside of Identity framework).

**UPD** I think I've misread your question. Seems like you have 2 instances of DbContext that play a tug-of-war. You have your own instance and another instance that is part of Identity. When you call `_db.SaveChanges()` you are saving changes in your context and it is flushed to a DB. At the same time you have another instance of DbContext that does not know anything about modifications that you have done already. And it tracks instance of that user (somewhere else) and keeps internal information about that user, but it does not query for an updated state of the related record in DB. And when you call `UserManager.AddToRole` that state is flushed back to DB again, but with the old values.

So your issue is really having 2 DbContexts.